# String to Integer in Javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers

this is code

```
const str = '1111';
console.log(Number(str));
```

But When String's length over 17, it will be have problem

```
const str = '111100000123121221234'
console.log(Number(str)); // 111100000123121220000
```

I want to know, what's the principle of convert string to Integer of Number Object. Why convert wrong

Thank You Very Much

Comment: You exceeded the maximum precision for integers in JS. That's why the number comes back "wrong".

Comment: Because that number is greater than MAX_SAFE_INTEGER(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because "Integers (numbers without a period or exponent notation) are accurate up to 15 digits". See: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp